Schema.org for a group of courses/a program?
I'm currently building the Schema.org for a college, and so I filled a bunch of courses. PE, French 101, that kind of stuff.
But now I'm looking to create the programs pages. I can't seem to figure out what I'm supposed to use. Like there is not a program schema, or something like that.
So how do I inform schema something like this
- Computer Science Diploma
-- Session 1
--- PE 1
--- Programming Languages 101
--- College Level English 101
-- Session 2
--- Programming languages 201
--- Databases 101
[etc]

Some other question on this site seems to mention ItemList, but it seems weird that it would be just a straight, unnamed list. Or am I simply thinking about it wrong?

You could use EducationalOccupationalProgram, as it seems to be relevant to your content:

A program offered by an institution which determines the learning
progress to achieve an outcome, usually a credential like a degree or
certificate

For example, you could use EducationalOccupationalProgram, at root level, and then to hasCourse property add  Courses in an array, and then, if it fits, they could serve as groups that have specific subjects as CourseInstance, also in an array added to hasCourseInstance:
EducationalOccupationalProgram -Computer Science Diploma
  Course - Session 1
    CourseInstance - Programming Languages 101
    ...
  Course - Session 2
    CourseInstance - Programming Languages 201
    ... 

see examples for each linked entity
json-ld demo:
<script type="application/ld+json">

{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "EducationalOccupationalProgram",
  "name": "Computer Science Diploma",
  "hasCourse": [
    {
    "@type": "Course",
    "name": "Session 1",
    "hasCourseInstance": [{
      "@type": "CourseInstance",
      "name": "Programming Languages 101"
    }, {
      "@type": "CourseInstance",
      "name": "College Level English 101"
    }]
  },
{
    "@type": "Course",
    "name": "Session 2",
    "hasCourseInstance": [{
      "@type": "CourseInstance",
      "name": "Programming languages 201"
    }, {
      "@type": "CourseInstance",
      "name": "Databases 101"
    }]
  }
]
}
</script>

